# Generating function in runtime dynamically to improve performace

Tags: .net, expression-trees

I have a small function which will be called super frequently, basically it checks a config value and decide which value to return:

```
string GetKey()
{
    if (Config.UseFirstName)
    {
         return this.firstName;
    }
    else
    {
         return this.lastName;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it is pretty simple, the `Config.UseFirstName` is a configurable variable that read from a local configuration file when starting up, once it is loaded, it will never be changed. Given that, I want to improve its performance by removing the `if-else` clause, I want to dynamically generate the `GetKey` function when `Config.UseFirstName` variable is determined during starting up, if it is true, then i will generate a function like this:

```
string GetKey()
{
    return this.firstName;
}
```

I hope by eliminating the unnecessary checking of boolean, the performance of this function can be improved, its behavior is similar to .DLL dynamic loading on Windows platform.
Now is the question, does .NET support my scenario? Should I use ExpressionTree?

Comment: An `if-else` clause with a condition based on a Boolean variable is unlikely to cause any kind of performance issue. Generating the function at startup would likely take more time that calling the function a million times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a function pointer

```
Func<string> GetKey;
```

In the class' constructor

```
MyClass()
{
    if (Config.UseFirstName)
    {
        GetKey = () => this.firstName;
    }
    else
    {
        GetKey = () => this.lastName;
    }
}
```

Calling GetKey will now just return the correct attribute without having to evaluate Config.UseFirstName.

Comment: This is a good solution. I want to ask a follow up question, is there a way to load a function's code from external text file and compile it when starts up, call it?

Comment: You can compile an assembly on the fly with CSharpCodeProvider. Keep in mind that you won't be able to inject functionality to your existing class. If you are aiming at performance. Best case, you will end up adding a call to a method on that compiled assembly, which looks worse to the option above. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider?view=netframework-4.7.2.

Comment: Thanks! I am writing a framework and sometimes user wants to specify the logic of function, instead of asking them to provide a plug-in assembly, i want to let them provide the code of function in text, which will be compiled in runtime.